# Check if a URL has anything after the domain name in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I’m trying to match any and every URL that contain only the domain name (e.g. `www.domain.com`, or `otherdomain.com\`) with regex. So `domain.com` or `domain.com/` should be matched but `domain.com/index` shouldn’t.

I’ve tried this:

```
^://[^/]*(/)?$
```

But it doesn’t seem to work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(?:https?://)?[^/]*(/)?$/i
```

Try this. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/1)

Comment: even taking off the `^` from the original regex would match non https urls, as in `://[^/]*/?$`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printf '%s\n' domain.com/index sub.domain.com/ domain.com |
    perl -lne 'm|/\w+| or print'
sub.domain.com/
domain.com
```